# Получение данных переменной из одного файла js в другой файл js

Tags: javascript, файлы, переменные

Имеется небольшая проблема. У меня есть глобальная переменная в одном файле js, и мне нужно получить ее значение во втором файле js. Казалось бы вроде как простая задача, в интернете полно предложений по переносу значений в другие файлы, но..., я перепробовал десятки способов, кодов и функций, и ни одна у меня не работает. Пробовал обозначать переменную как глобальную в первом файле и показать ее во втором файле, но была ошибка во втором файле, что эта переменная не обозначена, так же пробовал соединять два js файла в html файле, но тоже не получалось. Пытался присвоить  значение type='module', но выдавало ошибку. Пробовал переносить с помощью export и import, но были ошибки, что так нельзя сделать. В конце концов попробовал эту функцию:

```
srcipt_1.js:
window.Storage = {};
window.Storage = 100;
```

```
script_2.js:
var localVar = window.Storage;
console.log(localVar);
```

Это единственный на половину рабочий способ, который хотя бы не выводил ошибки в консоль, но опять же, результата нет... В консоль выводится следующее: *ƒ Storage() { [native code] }*

Мог бы кто то объяснить что это такое и каким образом в моем случае передать значение переменной из одного файла в другой?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Подробнее надо что у вас за проект. Если это просто кучка js файликов, то перенос должен работать при подключении их обоих  в html.
Со сторейджем можете попробовать использовать localStorage
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
let cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');

Comment: Всё, спасибо, разобрался. Забыл про этот способ, он работает, все в порядке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для импортирования и использования переменной из одного файла js в другой файл js можно использовать импорты.

Например, если вы хотите импортировать переменную `MY_VAR` из файла `my_file.js` в файл `my_other_file.js`, то в `my_other_file.js` вы должны добавить следующую строку:

```
import { Window.Storage } from './my_file.js';
```

Comment: Не MY_VAR a Window.Storage